# How to open up terminal (gui) at startup and execute a command?

Tags: boot, python, lxterminal

I want to be able to open up terminal (gui) on start up and execute a command inside that terminal. I'm placing this inside my /etc/rc.local

```
x-terminal-emulator -e python /home/pi/pythonFile.py
```

However this isn't working.. I must be doing something wrong here.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: give this a try gnome-terminal -e "python /home/pi/pythonFile.py" you may also want to check that you can run the python script from a terminal manually. You may also want to check out this question http://askubuntu.com/questions/351582/open-terminal-window-and-execute-python-script-on-startup

Answer (score 1):

This assumes you're running debian and doing this from inside a desktop environment: 
`sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal gnome-panel`
`gnome-desktop-icon-edit --create-new ~/.xdg/autostart/your-script.desktop`

In the window that appears, fill all fields and check the "run in terminal" box.

The script will now run in a terminal at login, and you can configure your display manager for auto login at this point if you haven't already done so.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem trying to run a python script in the terminal at start up, here is what I did.

SPECS:
Raspberry pi 3 running OS: Raspbian, Version: 9 (stretch)

1) Go to `/home/pi/.config/autostart` (If you cant find `.config` in `/home/pi`, <kbd>Right Click</kbd>  in window and check "Show Hidden").

2) Right click>Create New...>Empty File. Name it, [whatever].desktop

3) <kbd>Right Click</kbd> on the new file and open in text editor.

4) Pasted the following and edit it to your liking.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=[name of this file, i.e. step 2]
Comment=
Exec= lxterminal -e [Application, i.e. python3] [full path to the code you want to run]
Hidden=false
terminal=true
```

5) save and reboot.

*There are other things you can put into your`.desktop`file but this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be able to autostart a terminal with a python script that gets opened within that terminal, which is basically a `how do I autostart X, Y, or Z program` question. Shouldn't be too difficult.

The reason you placing that command within the `/etc/rc.local` file is failing is because the commands in `etc/rc.local` are executed as part of the boot sequence, prior to any logins or starting of the X11 server (GUI desktop). x-terminal-emulator is a GUI application, thus it requires a desktop to work.

The way to fix this is relatively simple. You will need to re-run `rpi-config` as you will need to turn on auto-boot to desktop. If you don't want to do that, things are going to be a lot more complicated.

Once boot-to-desktop is enabled you will need to create a script called `.xinitrc` in your home directory. Put whatever command you want auto-executed when the x server starts in this file. Once boot-to-desktop is enabled and the `xinitrc` script created reboot and the desktop should automatically start up and start your python script in the terminal!

Check [here](https://superuser.com/questions/150311/how-do-you-start-a-program-after-x-has-started) for another question that is basically the same as yours.

Hope this helps!